# How to uninstall apex-mdapi package

Tags: apex, mdapi

A while back, I installed mdapi (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from github using the 'Deploy to Salesforce' button.  We no longer need it, and it is taking up a lot of room in our Apex code, and also giving us test coverage issues.  So we want to delete it. Has anyone done this before, and if so, how you were able to do this?

Comment: Check this post on the mdapi github: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the `apex-mdapi` `package.xml` manifest into a `destructiveChanges.xml` uninstall manifest pretty easily.

1. Grab the project's [`package.xml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/master/apex-mdapi/src/package.xml).
2. Rename it to `destructiveChanges.xml`.
3. Make a copy of it called `package.xml`, but remove all of the `<types>` XML entities. `package.xml` should contain only

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
       <version>42.0</version>
   </Package>
   ```
4. Zip up the two files in the root directory of a zip file.
5. Log in to Workbench. (Preferably on a sandbox first!)
6. Go to Migration->Deploy. Select your zip file, and check Single Package. Click through to complete the deployment.

Because the package for `apex-mdapi` may change at any time - it's under version control and might be further developed - make sure to review it before you actually perform a destructive deployment.